# What's the "More than 20 comments posted" Flag?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When comments exceed 20](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101531/when-comments-exceed-20)

What is the `More than 20 comments posted` flag? Is it automatic or do people somehow set this flag?

What causes it, and why is having more than 20 comments bad?

Comment: I don't think flag generally speaking mean `bad`, it means more `It needs moderator attention`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing, and my conclusion (absolutely baseless actually) was that it's not necessarily bad, but it could be a sign of flames going on in there, and thus the flag. Just a mark to get some attention and perhaps do some cleaning if required.

Comment: yes, exactly -- it's unusual and worth highlighting. Also, posting an extremely long question or answer (25k+ chars) is an automatic moderator flag as well for the same reasons.

Comment: @Jeff great! That means I'm slowly getting how this works :)

Comment: Also, it would encourage a transition to Chat to continue a conversation, if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

It is set automatically when a post has more than 20 comments posted. A large number of comments often indicates that a discussion that would be better fit for chat is taking place in the comment space.

Comment: Isn't that basically a `too chatty` flag?

Comment: So what should I do when I see such a flag in the review? What happens after I second it?