# When comments exceed 20

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, flags

I wonder whether it wouldn't be a good idea to change the automatic flagging when a post exceeds 20 comments to be based on the *rate* of commenting instead of just the total number.

When SO was relatively new, there was little effective difference between the two, but it's been around long enough now that we're starting to see quite a few posts that have 20 or more comments, without that really indicating much except that the post has been around for a few years. While it's not particularly *crucial* to keep such posts from being flagged, it does add noise while seeming to accomplish relatively little. 20 comments entered over the course of something like 3 years does not seem to be particularly noteworthy, whereas 20 comments entered in the course of a day or two generally is.

Comment: I was considering a proposal to squelch it completely, given that problematic comment threads usually carry flags. I like this idea a lot more, it would reveal the noise without creating more for us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Awesome idea - we will now no longer flag a post for 20 or more comments unless these comments were made within a period of 3 days.  This will be in the next build.