# What is pruning by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, edits, moderators

On a semi-controversial [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481937/simple-c-sharp-array-throwing-outofmemory-exception) I just recently asked, I was told to update the question with the relevant comment details (which I'm working on), that the question was being "monitored for pruning" by casperOne.

What exactly does "monitored for pruning" mean? I haven't found any definition of this on the FAQ in StackOverflow, or meta.

I'm updating my question with the details regardless...but I was just curious what was meant by the phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It relates exactly to what was suggested: pruning of the comments. Due to the number of comments and their content, someone is watching it and the comments are likely to be pruned - deleted.

Answer (score 5):

I was alerted to the comment stream because of [Community's "more than 20 posts in three (3) days" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101531/when-comments-exceed-20) that came up.

The fact all of the comments caused you to update your question is a good thing.  It will more than likely draw better answers and provide quality information for those who have the same (or similar) question in the future.

However, the state of the question and the comment stream at the time had indicated that the question was moving away from being a quality question.

This is why I responded with [the "pruning" comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481937/simple-c-sharp-array-throwing-outofmemory-exception#comment-10514463); comment streams are not meant to detract from the integrity of the question and/or answer, they are meant to help *evolve* the question and/or answer, as they have in this case.

When a comment stream *does* get out of hand, then a moderator will usually purge all of the comments (i.e. delete all of them).

When I said "pruning", I was trying to indicate in a friendly way that I was going to trim the comment stream down if action had not been taken to improve the quality of the question and/or answer.

Now that's been done, I would recommend that you delete the comments that you can that are no longer relevant, or, if the entire stream is not relevant anymore, we can do that for you.

**TL;DR version**

"pruning" is a term I used to indicate I was going to delete comments if they weren't being cleaned up, as they were detracting from the question and/or answer.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this and delete everything before "TL;DR version"